# Flickering on TListView and older versions of C++ Builder

Tags: drag-and-drop, c++builder, vcl, c++builder-6

In my current project I need to work with an older version of C++ Builder (5).

I tried to implement drag and drop on a TListView with

- MultiSelect
- DragMode dmManual
- BeginDrag()

The dragging code is very simple:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ListView1MouseMove( TObject *Sender, TShiftState Shift, int X, int Y)
{
    if ( Shift.Contains( ssLeft ) )
    {

        // if ( !dynamic_cast< TControl * >( Sender )->Dragging() )
        if ( !static_cast< TControl * >( Sender )->Dragging() )
        {
            ListView1->BeginDrag( false );
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works pretty fine as long as I compile and run this code on newer versions of C++ Builder (e.g. XE2 or XE10). But when I compile this code on C++ Builder 5 or C++ Builder 6 the ListView control shows an ugly behaviour: As soon as I start dragging one of the Items in the ListView a very heavy flickering appears, which makes the mouse cursor almost immoveable.

Now my Question: Is it possible to implement a **flicker-free** dragging on these **old versions** of C++ Builder which uses dmManual with MultiSelect?

Additional stuff:

The ListView is populated this way:

```
void __fastcall TFormMain::ButtonPopulateListViewClick(TObject *Sender)
{
    for ( int i = 0; i < 20; ++i )
    {
        AnsiString Name = System::Sysutils::Format( "Record Nr. %d", ARRAYOFCONST(( i )) );
        TListItem *ListItem = ListView1->Items->Add();

        ListItem->Data = new Record( Name, i );

        ListItem->Caption = Name;
    }
}
```

...and this is the Record class:

```
class Record
{
    private:
        AnsiString Name;
        int Value;
    public:
        Record( AnsiString AName, int AValue ) : Name( AName ), Value( AValue ) {}

        AnsiString GetName( void ) { return Name; };
};
```

Edit:

I know that flickering disappears when I switch to dmAutomatic and use the OnStartDrag() event of the TListView. But due to other reasons that is not an option and therefore not the answer to my question.

Thanks!

Comment: FYI, using `dynamic_cast` in this example is wasteful. You KNOW the `Sender` is `ListView1`, so just use `ListView1->Dragging()` instead. Or at least use `static_cast` instead: `if (!static_cast<TListView*>(Sender)->Dragging())`.  You don't need the runtime overhead that `dynamic_cast` performs.  Also, `reinterpret_cast<TObject*>(rec)` is just plain wrong. `TListItem::Data` is a `void*`, you don't need a cast at all: `ListItem->Data = rec;`

Comment: In any case, when you use `dmAutomatic`, the ListView calls `BeginDrag(false)` internally in response to `WM_LBUTTONDOWN`, so I doubt this is the source of your issue.

Comment: @RemyLebeau thank you for your suggestions. I removed the inefficient casts so my example got more understandable. But my question remains: Why does it flicker on CB6 and not on CB XE2. Upgrading or dmAutomatic are no options.

Comment: WHY is hard to answer without doing a diff between the two versions of VCL source code. There is a HUGE gap of time (9 years) between CB6 and XE2, a lot of changes and fixes between them.